# Is it possible to override the default Gallery Settings form?

Tags: filters, gallery

I'm trying to change the options that are presented for the gallery settings. I can't seem to find a hook or override that gets exactly what I want. I came close with the following, but it only seems to add to the top of the tab.

```
function media_upload_gallery(){
echo 'test';    
}

add_filter('media_upload_gallery', 'media_upload_gallery');
```

Is it even possible to hook into that form and either replace it or edit it?

Levi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to alter the gallery settings. About the only thing you can do is to override the entire gallery shortcode. You can technically have your users pass any sort of parameters into the shortcode and recognize them with your alternate gallery.

Simply use:

```
add_filter('post_gallery', 'foo_override_gallery', 1, 2);
function foo_override_gallery($empty, $attr){
    //Extract the attributes
    //Create your own gallery layout
    return $output;
}
```

By returning any value to the filter, the default gallery is completely overridden. You must **return** HTML for this to work properly.

I know this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it's the closest way to customize the output of the gallery shortcode. I dumped the gallery template here sans the override filter that you could put in your new function: http://pastie.org/4293527

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I see what you mean by not being able to override the settings the way I want to. The form is essentially hard coded in /wp-admin/includes/media.php. I'm still hoping to figure out a way to make this easy for the client to toggle on and off so that I do not need to rely on them typing in the attribute. Your code snippet guided me in the right direction though, so thanks!

Comment: @Levi Let us know what you come up with.